# Who supported Kauravas and Pandavas from south India?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, war, kurukshetra, kauravas

Who ruled South India during Mahabharata time?
Please tell me who supported Kauravas and Pandavas from south India?

With reference

Comment: Arjuna married Chitrangada princess' of Pandya king is

Comment: @Prasanna R she was Princess of Manipur ....

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan